# Parsing a pipe-delimited file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, csv

I'm trying to parse a pipe-delimited file and pass the values into a list, so that later I can print selective values from the list.

The file looks like:

```
name|age|address|phone|||||||||||..etc
```

It has more than 100 columns.

Comment: A good question will have a sample code and any errors you get when trying to run the code.

Comment: @jwodder: Whatever the reason, it seems to have worked: this question got two valid answers, while the other one got none and was auto-deleted. Voting to reopen, despite the awful score.

Comment: I am ***so*** pleased that the attempt to close this question failed on the second attempt!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you're parsing a very simple file that won't contain any `|` characters in the actual field values, you can use [`split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
fileHandle = open('file', 'r')

for line in fileHandle:
    fields = line.split('|')

    print(fields[0]) # prints the first fields value
    print(fields[1]) # prints the second fields value

fileHandle.close()
```

A more robust way to parse tabular data would be to use the `csv` library as [mentioned in Spencer Rathbun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15956440/365796).

Comment: i have used the split string method, but it only prints "n" from the the first split column(name).

Comment: If you literally copy and paste my code into a text file and run it, you will see that it works. Perhaps you could share some of your code so we can see what's going wrong?

Comment: with open("abc.txt","r" ) as infile:
    data = infile.read()
    fields = data.split('|')
    print(data[0])

Comment: This method won't work if one of the fields has a pipe in it. Using the actual CSV library will manage that much better.

Answer (score 43):

Use the ['csv' library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

First, register your dialect:

```
import csv
csv.register_dialect('piper', delimiter='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

Then, use your dialect on the file:

```
with open(myfile, "rb") as csvfile:
    for row in csv.DictReader(csvfile, dialect='piper'):
        print row['name']
```

Comment: I am thankful for the proposed solution but I ran into some minor problems. The error  "iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)" was solved by adding **encoding='utf-8'** to the *open()* statement.The second problem was solved using **mode='r'** instead of **mode='rb'** as given in the solution.

Answer (score 22):

Use [Pandas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandas_%28software%29):

```
import pandas as pd

pd.read_csv(filename, sep="|")
```

This will store the file in a dataframe. For each column, you can apply conditions to select the required values to print. It takes a very short time to execute. I tried with 111,047 rows.

Comment: Perhaps extend the sample code to extract individual values?

Answer (score 3):

In 2022, with Python 3.8 or above, you can simply do:

```
import csv

with open(file_path, "r") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='|')
    for row in reader:
        print(row[0], row[1])
```

Comment: With a valid input file, this results in "`NameError: name 'csv' is not defined`". Can you [make it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71309191/edit) self-contained? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today. See e.g. [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230693), [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/127655), and [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/378081).)

Comment: And perhaps extend the sample code to extract some column values?

Comment: You just need to import the `csv` module. I have added that.
For columns, row[0], row[1], ..  should give you the first and second column, and so on