# output data into text file as data is streaming in for python

Tags: python, fileoutputstream

the following code reads in a file line by line. What would be the most efficient way to output each lines in to a text file (output.txt) as the lines are being Read in from the input file?

```
fileHandle = open('file', 'r')

for line in fileHandle:
    fields = line.split('|')

    print(fields[0]) # prints the first fields value
    print(fields[1]) # prints the second fields value

fileHandle.close()
```

The code above was found in [Parsing a pipe delimited file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15956169/parsing-a-pipe-delimited-file-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

An efficient way is to use *generators* with *context managers* to handle the files. The context manager takes care for closing the file. The generator will yield one line at a time, instead of building a temp list first.

```
with open('read_file', 'r') as reader:
    with open('output_file', 'w') as writer:
        gen = (line.split('|') for line in reader)
        for row in gen:
            writer.write(row)
```

Comment: Thanks. If my first line of input txt file is |AA | BB|11|, how would I get it to output in the format |AA|11|?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the pandas version where we can do this in a very readable way:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('infile.csv', sep="|")
df.iloc[:,:2].to_csv('outfile.csv', sep="|", index=False)
```

The key here is:

```
df.iloc[:,:2] # selects the first two columns
```

Example by creating a file-like object:

```
import io
s = u"""A|B|C
1|2|3
4|5|6"""

file = io.StringIO(s)

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(file, sep="|")
output = df.iloc[:,:2].to_csv(sep="|", index=False)
print(output)
```

Returns:

```
A|B
1|2
4|5
```

Comment: don't you think what using pandas in tasks like this is a huge overkill?

Comment: @ailin Sometimes I do and it might be the case here. However the fact you get a bunch of output options, can easily do operations like merge,split,sum ... makes it the right choice for almost all tasks.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it, I open an input file on 'read' and an output file on 'write'. I got this answer from a Python textbook. It says python can handle multiple files being open at once. Just make sure to add the reference to the print statement "file=outfile". Then of course close both files.

```
infile = open(infileName,'r')
outfile = open(outfileName,'w')

for line in infile:
    fields = line.split('|')

    print(fields[0], file=outfile)
    print(fields[1], file=outfile)

infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

Comment: Thanks. If my first line of input txt file is  
|AA | BB|11|,

how would I get it to output in the format

|AA|11|?

Comment: @Dan after you assign the variable 'fields' you can use concatenation to merge the values together. for examples: print(fields[0]+"|"+fields[2])